# Include the result of cat into a command in a Makefile (Windows)

Tags: powershell, makefile

I have a Makefile with the following recipe:

```
test:
   echo "$$(cat ~/.ssh/id__something)"
```

If I run `make test` on MacOS (I assume any UNIX like system), this will echo the content on the file preserving line breaks, etc.

But If I run this on Windows I get the following output:

```
"$(cat ~/.ssh/id__something)"
```

Meaning, the `cat` command wasn't executed. Note that I'm using power shell, and `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content`.

Note that If I do `cat ~/.ssh/id__something` I get the expected result.

So, my question would be how to get the result of the command inside the makefile recipe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Note that I'm using power shell_ : no, you're not.  You're using `make`.  Make is invoking this process, not your shell.  The question is, what shell does _make_ use to invoke it's recipes.  This depends on how your version of make was built: some versions invoke UNIX-like shells (assuming one can be found).  Others invoke Windows `cmd.exe`.  No version of make I'm aware of will invoke powershell (certainly not by default).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MadScientist,. I am using `GNU Make 4.3` built for Windows. Installed with `scoop`. Now, not sure on which shell it is invoking. I do have `bash` that comes with the `git` installer for windows, but definitely not using that one, because when running the recipe on that one, it runs as expected. Also tried it out on `cmd` and same unwanted result. I would expect it executes the commands in the invoking shell? I'll try to dig into it, but in the meantime do you have any more insights?

Comment: Maybe it depends on $SHELL?  Try get-content instead.  "On MS-DOS, if SHELL is not set, the value of the variable COMSPEC (which is always set) [C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe] is used instead." https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by _it executes the commands in the invoking shell_ but no matter what you mean I think that's not right.  If you mean make actually runs commands in the instance of the shell that started make, that's not possible (you can't run a command in your parent process).  If you mean make runs a new instance of the same type shell as the shell that it was invoked with, that's also not true: that would be a disaster for portability since it means whatever shell the user was running would impact the build.

Comment: make runs commands in the shell specified by the `SHELL` make variable.  That value is set to `/bin/sh` on a POSIX system.  On Windows it's unfortunately complicated.  I think that if make can find a `sh` program it uses that, and if not it will use `cmd.exe`.  If you want something different you can set the `SHELL` variable ini your makefile.

Comment: Thanks to your comments I was able to understand what the SHELL variable it is. In fact, the `COMSPEC` was set to `cmd`. So `cat` or `Get-Content` won't work, so I used `type` (for `cmd`). Now, I think my question has an answer here within the comments. Feel free to write it and I'll accept it. 

Now I have another that after looking at some of @MadScientist answers all over StackOverflow it seems that can't be done. The file I need the content from has carriage return, and you said can not be preserved when loaded into a variable using `shell`. Am I right?

Comment: Correct; just as in POSIX sh `$(...)` or backticks, newlines are converted to spaces in the results of make's `$(shell ...)` function.

Comment: Understood, thank you. So I am left to figure out on how to read and pass this multi line file content as argument for a different command (docker build .... --build-arg $MULTILINE_SSH_KEY) or probably find a different way to do it.

Comment: If by `MULTILINE_SSH_KEY` you mean a private key, that's not the typical way to do it (and, it's insecure since anyone can see the arguments at the command line).  Usually you give the command a filename of the key.  If it's a public key, those are usually a single line.

Comment: @MadScientist, neither `$(...)` nor `\`...\`` _in and of themselves_ convert newlines to spaces. That only happens if you use these command substitutions _unquoted_, in which case the _shell expansion_ called _word splitting_ kicks in - in a POSIX-compatible shell, compare `echo $(printf 'a\nb')` to `echo "$(printf 'a\nb')"`

Comment: Yes, but there's no such thing as "quoting" in makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, [`make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) uses `cmd.exe` as the default shell for invoking shell commands, not PowerShell - this is independent of what shell you happen to be calling `make` *from*.

You can instruct `make` to use Windows PowerShell instead, by placing the following at the top of your `Makefile`:

```
SHELL := powershell.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command
```

While doing so enables you to use *PowerShell-specific syntax* in your make files, formulating *cross-platform* commands won't be possible, except in very simple cases: while PowerShell offers *aliases* for its cmdlets named for standard Unix utilities (e.g., `cat` for `Get-Content`, `ls` for `Get-ChildItem`), the fundamentally different syntax of these cmdlets compared to their Unix counterparts makes platform-agnostic calls all but impossible.

Using *PowerShell syntax*, you could then pass the content of a file as a multi-line string as follows:

```
test:
   echo (Get-Content -Raw ~/.ssh/id__something)
```

Comment: Awesome, I got the content preserving the multi-line. It was echoed out perfectly. However I´m trying to use the result as input for a command. For instance: In my recipe I´m doing:
`docker build --rm --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$$(Get-Content -Raw ~/.ssh/id__something)" -f Dockerfile -t something .`. I was expecting to get the content as that argument, but I'm just getting the actual command, not the result of the execution. I may be doing something wrong with the escape characters and double quotes, right?

Comment: After playing around with it I got it working: `docker build --rm --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$$(Get-Content -Raw ~/.ssh/id__guava) -f Dockerfile -t something .`. Thank you very much +1 @mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it, @DarK_FirefoX; my pleasure. Both your most recent command and the one with `"..."` should work, but only when called from `make`, due to the _doubled_ `$` (which is required for `make` to pass a `$` through). When executed directly in PowerShell, `$$` refers to the last argument on the _previously_ executed command line.